# Calling multiple APIs slows down the app to load?

Tags: api, flutter, dart

So I have made a News App using APIs available on the internet. So I had to use different  API for each different Category. There are more than 9 categories, So this is making my app load very slow. So, what is the solution to this. How can I only call 2 APIs at the initial state and rest of the others after some time when the app has loaded.
See the code below:

```
class NewsCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewsCardState createState() => _NewsCardState();
}

class _NewsCardState extends State<NewsCard>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController tabController;
  static DateTime now = DateTime.now();
  String formattedDate;
  List newsData;
  List topNews1;
  List businessNews1;
  List worldNews1;
  List sportsNews1;
  List entertainmentNews1;
  List educationNews1;
  List tvnews1;
  List electionNews1;
  List lifeNews1;
  bool isLoading = true;
  final String toi= "https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/";
  final String topNews =
      "API url";
  final String sportsNews =
      "API url";

  final String businessNews =
      "API url";

  final String worldNews =
      "API url ";
  final String entertainmentNews =
      "API url ";
  final String educationNews =
      "API url";
  final String tvNews =
      "API url ";
  final String electionNews =
      "API url";
  final String lifeNews =
      "API url";

  final String url =
      "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news-in&apiKey=";

  Future getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(url),
      headers: {
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: ""
      },
    );
    var response1 = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(topNews),
    );
    var response2 = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(businessNews),
    );
    var response3 = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(worldNews),
    );
    var response4 = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(sportsNews),
    );
    var response5 = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(entertainmentNews),
    );
    var response6 = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(tvNews),
    );
    var response7 = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(lifeNews),
    );
    var response8 = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(electionNews),
    );
    var response9 = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull(educationNews),
    );
    List data = jsonDecode(response.body)['articles'];
    List topNewsData = jsonDecode(response1.body)['stories'];
    List businessNewsData = jsonDecode(response2.body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    List worldNewsData = jsonDecode(response3.body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    List sportsNewsData = jsonDecode(response4.body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    List entertainmentNewsData = jsonDecode(response5.body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    List tvNewsData = jsonDecode(response6.body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    List lifeNewsData = jsonDecode(response7.body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    List electionsNewsData = jsonDecode(response8.body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    List educationNewsData = jsonDecode(response9.body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    setState(() {
      newsData = data;
      topNews1 = topNewsData;
      businessNews1 = businessNewsData;
      worldNews1 = worldNewsData;
      sportsNews1 = sportsNewsData;
      entertainmentNews1 = entertainmentNewsData;
      tvnews1 = tvNewsData;
      lifeNews1=lifeNewsData;
      electionNews1 = electionsNewsData;
      educationNews1  = educationNewsData;
      isLoading = false; //this is for the initial loading, this is taking too much of time.
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    this.getData();
    tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 9);
  }
```

Inside the Scaffold

```
isLoading
                ?Column(....):Column(.....)
```

Do keep in Mind that i am a beginner in Flutter, So if my method of approach is wrong then kindly request me to do the perfect approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is no dependency between different api calls (api call 1 need not wait for api call 0 to finish), better to start them all and await for the results at end. So don't use `await` for every api call. Instead use [Future.wait](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.5.2/dart-async/Future/wait.html) to wait for all futures at the end. Something like:

```
  Future getData() async {
    List<Future> responseFutures = [
      http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(url),
        headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: ""},
      ),
      http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(topNews),
      ),
      http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(businessNews),
      ),
      http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(worldNews),
      ),
      http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(sportsNews),
      ),
      http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(entertainmentNews),
      ),
      http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(tvNews),
      ),
      http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(lifeNews),
      ),
      http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(electionNews),
      ),
      http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull(educationNews),
      ),
    ];
    List responses = await Future.wait(responseFutures);

    List data = jsonDecode(responses[0].body)['articles'];
    List topNewsData = jsonDecode(responses[1].body)['stories'];
    List businessNewsData = jsonDecode(responses[2].body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    List worldNewsData = jsonDecode(responses[3].body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    List sportsNewsData = jsonDecode(responses[4].body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    List entertainmentNewsData = jsonDecode(responses[5].body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    List tvNewsData = jsonDecode(responses[6].body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    List lifeNewsData = jsonDecode(responses[7].body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    List electionsNewsData = jsonDecode(responses[8].body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    List educationNewsData = jsonDecode(responses[9].body)['items'][0]['stories'];
    setState(() {
      newsData = data;
      topNews1 = topNewsData;
      businessNews1 = businessNewsData;
      worldNews1 = worldNewsData;
      sportsNews1 = sportsNewsData;
      entertainmentNews1 = entertainmentNewsData;
      tvnews1 = tvNewsData;
      lifeNews1 = lifeNewsData;
      electionNews1 = electionsNewsData;
      educationNews1 = educationNewsData;
      isLoading = false; //this is for the initial loading, this is taking too much of time.
    });
  }
```

Comment: So should i remove the future with await and use future.wait instead?

Comment: I didn't get you. My point is don't wait for previous call to finish (Don't use `await`) to start next call. Start all of them once, wait for all futures to be over using `Future.wait`. Check `Future.wait` documentation in link mentioned. I have also added explicit types to make it more readable.

Comment: This error is coming: Only static members can be accessed in initializers

Comment: Above code should still be in `getData()` function. I just refactored how you should make api calls.

Comment: so i should remove async from getData()?

Comment: I pasted entire `getData` hope you can understand now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201091/discussion-between-maadhav-sharma-and-chenna-reddy).